# Path params within @Path annotation, which is better

Tags: java, rest, path, jax-rs, query-string

simple question from me.

Case: Need to write endpoint that looks like `@Path({id}/{type})`

1. Only static `ID` and `TYPE`

   ```
   @Path("{" + ID + "}/{" + TYPE "}")
   public void doSth(@PathParam(ID) String Id, @PathParam(TYPE) String type) {}
   ```
2. Static `PATH_XXX` too

   ```
   static final String PATH_ID = "{" + ID + "}";
   static final String PATH_TYPE = "{" + TYPE + "}";

   @Path(PATH_ID + SLASH + PATH_TYPE)
   public void doSth(@PathParam(ID) String Id, @PathParam(TYPE) String type) {}
   ```

What do you guys think of it, which is better to use?

Comment: What do you consider "better"?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with

```
@Path("{id}/{type}")
public void doSth(@PathParam("id") String id, @PathParam("type") String type) {}
```

- it respects the Java naming conventions
- it's much more readable than what you have
- it's shorter than what you have
- the IDE, then the framework and/or your tests will tell you that something is wrong if you happen to make a typo in one of the strings, which has almost zero chance of happening anyway.